# How to make array of Tkinter widgets OOP method?

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have an array of Tkinter widgets that are not object oriented:

```
Image_col = [
    tk.Button(
        frame,
        image=root.render1,
        relief="raised",
        bg="light gray",
        # width = ColWidths[j],
        command=lambda y=y: change_img(y)
    )
    for y in range(0, rq)
]
```

In order to use a special function, in which I pass the widget `self.ButtonA` as an argument, (as I did in an oversimplified version of my app below) it seems that I will need to now take an object-oriented approach, and define a class that I can repeatedly use.

```
class MinCodeEx:
    global waitingforImage
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.ButtonA = tk.Button(width=60,height=40,command = lambda: self.UpdateImg())
        self.ButtonA.pack()
        self.ButtonA.img = None

    def UpdateImg(self):
        newDialog = snipping_tool.AcquireImage(self.master, self.ButtonA)
```

How else could I attach a function like `UpdateImage` (above) to every tk.Button within `Image_col`? It doesn't seem possible without taking an OOP aproach. My question is this: How should I structure `Image_col` in an OOP way? This seems close, but it doesn't work for me. Something must be missing:

```
class ImageCol(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, y):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.y = y
        self.btn = tk.Button(
                    frame,
                    image=root.render1,
                    relief="raised",
                    bg="blue",
                    #bg="light gray",
                    # width = ColWidths[j],
                    command=lambda y=y: self.change_img)
    def change_img(self):
        snipping_tool.AcquireImage(self.master, self.btn)

j: int = 1
Image_col = [
    ImageCol(frame, y)
    for y in range(0, rq)
]
```

Let me know if you need more of my code. It's challenging for me to shorten it into a minimum viable example in order to display it here.

Probably the most useful thing to note is that `change_image(y)` is supposed to change the image associated with the tkinter button with `index = y`.

Comment: One problem with your `ImageCol` class is that it defines a `tk.Button` subclass that contains a separate `tk.Button` _instance_ inside it. While certainly possible, it seems awkward and is unnecessary since a subclass instance is also an instance of the baseclass—so it could be implemented better—but since you haven't provided runnable code, posting an answer seems like too much work. It doesn't necessarily need to be subclass, and instead could just be a custom class, but  there's not enough information in your question to determine whether that would better a better approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and the function wasn't being runned. I have solved that by changing:
`command=lambda y=y: self.change_img` to `command=self.change_img`. You don't have to tell the class which button is it, as you already do it with `self`.

Just some features I removed in order to test (I don't think it should affect the program, but if it's still failing, check those first): I removed the button image (as I didn't have any), I replaced the `change_img()` content to a simple print with the buttonID (or y), replaced `rq` with a random integer, and i added `import tkinter as tk; frame = tk.Tk()` at the begining of the script and `tk.mainloop()` at the very end.